# Export Multpile Tables Data as Insert Statements in to single file Oracle DB

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have some tables data to be exported as Insert statements into a single flat/text file. The idea is to review the data before importing to the Oracle database

Can someone give any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you export it as csv and then, after reviewing, import that csv file into a flat table with ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL etc. Check this for the export: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_export%20table_to_csv.htm and this as well http://dba-oracle.com/t_export_schema_to_csv_file_all_tables.htm

Comment: Hi William, Thanks for the link but it shows only from a single table to export. What i am looking for is to export multiple tables (If possible) as I have hundreds of tables to be exported.

Comment: I envy the lucky person who gets to review screeds of insert statements for "hundreds of tables" :)